# Android passing data between Activities (Singleton) on Galaxy Note does not work

Tags: java, android, android-intent, singleton, galaxy

I've faced a problem on Galaxy Note (gt-n7000). It appeared that I can't pass data between two activities directly via startActivity(intent) due to some changed demands. So I've implemented a Singleton class:

```
public class IntentStack {
private static IntentStack instance;
private Map<String, Stack<Intent>> IntentMap = new HashMap<String, Stack<Intent>>();

    public synchronized static IntentStack getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new IntentStack();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private synchronized Stack<Intent> getStack(String key) {
        if (IntentMap.containsKey(key)) 
            return IntentMap.get(key);
        else 
            return null;
    }

    public synchronized Intent getTopIntent(String key) {
        if (IntentMap.containsKey(key)) {
            if (!getStack(key).isEmpty())
                return IntentMap.get(key).pop();
            else 
                return null;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public synchronized void addIntent (String key, Intent intent) {
        Stack<Intent> newStack;
        if (IntentMap.containsKey(key)) {
            newStack = IntentMap.get(key);
        } else {
            newStack = new Stack<Intent>();
        }
        newStack.push(intent);
        IntentMap.put(key, newStack);
    }

    public synchronized void clearIntents(String key) {
        IntentMap.remove(key);
    }
```

}

In my first activity I put a data in IntentStack like this:

```
IntentStack.getInstance().addIntent(Core.getIm().getClassName("photobill"), takePictureIntent);
```

In my second Activity I try to get an Intent:

```
Intent i = IntentStack.getInstance().getTopIntent(Core.getIm().getClassName("photobill"));
```

Where Core.getIm().getClassName(string) get its values from the Map, which is initialized on the Application start.

The problem is that `Intent i` is `null` but only on Galaxy Note (gt-n7000). On the other phones code works properly.

What could possibly cause such behavior? And what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Android does not guarantee that a static variable will retains its value. If the device starts to run short of resources (memory) it will "de-allocate" static variables. This could be you case.

To start, I would add log in

```
if (instance == null) {
   //ADD LOG HERE
   instance = new IntentStack();
}
```

to see if you are creating a new instance or not.

Comment: Log was added. IntentStack is created only once just how it's supposed to be.